# Forcing the order of output fields from cut command

Tags: unix, shell, awk, freebsd, gnu-coreutils

I want to do something like this:

```
cat abcd.txt | cut -f 2,1
```

and I want the order to be 2 and then 1 in the output. On the machine I am testing (FreeBSD 6), this is not happening (its printing in 1,2 order). Can you tell me how to do this?

I know I can always write a shell script to do this reversing, but I am looking for something using the 'cut' command options.

I think I am using version 5.2.1 of coreutils containing cut.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This can't be done using `cut`. According to the man page:

> Selected input is written in the same order that it is read, and is
>   written exactly once.

Patching `cut` has been [proposed](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2005-06/msg00125.html) [many](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-09/msg00020.html) [times](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-09/msg00169.html), but even [complete patches have been rejected](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2012-12/msg00115.html).

Instead, you can do it using `awk`, like this:

```
awk '{print($2,"\t",$1)}' abcd.txt
```

Replace the `\t` with whatever you're using as field separator.

Comment: Folks may be coming here confused because this (mis)behavior isn't documented in the `cut` man page found on \*BSD/macOS. The man page references the POSIX.2 standard which does indeed specify the output order.

Answer (score 22):

Lars' answer was great but I found an even better one. The issue with his is it matches \t\t as no columns. To fix this use the following:

```
awk -v OFS="  " -F"\t" '{print $2, $1}' abcd.txt
```

Where:

`-F"\t"` is what to cut on *exactly* (tabs).

`-v OFS="  "` is what to seperate with (two spaces)

Example:

```
echo 'A\tB\t\tD' | awk -v OFS="    " -F"\t" '{print $2, $4, $1, $3}'
```

This outputs:

```
B    D    A
```

Comment: In Cygwin I had to replace -F"\t" with -F \t to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `perl` version, just for my reference:

```
cat abcd.txt | perl -ne 'chomp; @F=split; print("$F[1]\t$F[0]\n")'
```

I use the `split` explicitly because I often only want to split on `\t` (`split("\t")`).