# How to change the field sequence in cut command in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want to print the fields in specific format , 
Input :

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
```

I used `cat file | cut -d '|' -f 3,1,4`
output :

```
col1|col3|col4
```

But my expected output is:

```
col3|col1|col4
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing the order of output fields from cut command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037171/forcing-the-order-of-output-fields-from-cut-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man cut`:

> Selected input is written in the same order that it is read, and is written exactly once

You should do:

```
$ awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{print $3,$1,$4}'  <<< "col1|col2|col3|col4"
col3|col1|col4
```

Answer (score 0):

even though awk is good,here is a perl solution:

```
perl -F"\|" -ane 'print join "|",@F[2,0,3]'
```

tested:

```
> echo "col1|col2|col3|col4" | perl -F"\|" -ane 'print join "|",@F[2,0,3]'
col3|col1|col4
```